# HTTP get in app.module.ts

Tags: angular, api, typescript

I'm trying to read some credentials from a server and add it to my route in `app.module.ts`

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'operation-log', component: OperationLogComponent },
    { path: 'person-concepts', component: frmPersonBegrepp },
    { path: 'payslip-setup', component: LönespecifikationComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/payslip-setup'+getCredentials(), pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

I don't know how to implement `getCredentials()`. I don't have a `constructor` to initiate `HttpClient`. I managed to create a function like this but it return an `Observable`

```js
function getCredentials() {
    if (!environment.production) {
       return (new HttpClient(HttpHandler.prototype)).get('http://localhost:3000')
    }
}
```

What is the right way to perform this?

Comment: what is the expected route path? you cannot declare routes this way

Comment: Of course you have a constructor ! Every typescript class has one. Just because it isn't written by the CLI doesn't mean it doesn't exist :)

Comment: @Aravind I want to add a string to the url to authenticate in dev environment. like "payslips-setup?amid= 91E3C1D4-5AB1-4351-AF5B-E17D910DA7CB"